# I am trying to export data to excel

Tags: alasql

I am trying to export data to excel .using alasql

but i am getting [object object] in excel sheet .

```
    var sql = 'SELECT INTO XLSX("' + dashboardName + '.xlsx",?) FROM ?';
    var res = alasql(sql, [sheetNames, exportData]);
```

Comment: can you share the format of your data?

Comment: var data1 = [{a:1,b:10},{a:2,b:20}];
var data2 = [{a:100,b:10},{a:200,b:20}];
var exportData = [data1,data2];
@MuhammadKamran this is the format of  data, can you help

Comment: I had added the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64212306/alasql-excel-from-json-styling-in-multiple-sheets with all data and outputs can you please check